# Custom Sort Items in an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` is a user defined class. I need to bind only few items of this ObservableCollection to a ComboBox and I want to show those items in a custom order in the dropdown.

Lets say the Observable Collection has items like:

```
Apple
Dog
Banana
Push
Mac
Keyboard
```

and lets suppose I want to show only these items in this exact order.

```
Apple
Mac
Dog
Banana
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you expose sort and filter conditions?

Comment: That seems like an awfully arbitrary sort/filter. Are there any rules to pick those items? You can't bind to "just a few" of a collection, but you can bind to a separate property that only returns those items.

Comment: There aren't any rules. I was thinking of going through each items on the original list like a foreach loop, and adding the required items to a different list and binding that list to the combobox. But is there a better way to add items on the second list instead of finding the first item first, second item second and adding them?

Comment: @Butters Sure, if there is some mechanism for determining whether a given item is one that should be moved.  Without one, it's an unsolvable problem, period, since you don't know what to copy.

Comment: How do you choose the required items?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I already know what items to display. But, I was looking for an easier way than looping through each items on that collection, finding the first item, adding that item to the next collection, looping again and finding the second item and so on.

Comment: To help you we also need to know what items to display and how to choose them.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan There is no way to choose them. We already know what items to display and also know that those items are in that collection. Now, I guess the only way is to find the first item, add to a new collection, find second - add to that collection and so on